# SQL Where statement with CASE variable

Tags: sql, variables, case

Im sorry I do not have a complete query because my original is actually very long but I feel you may be able to spot where I have an error in my syntax. Basically I declare 2 variables and if one variable is blank I need the where statement to be where the field is not in the other variable.

```
Where dnCP_FromServiceDate >= '01/01/2016' And
dnCP_FromServiceDate <= '01/31/2016' And
dnCP_RecordStatus <> 'V' 
AND CASE  WHEN @inpDXIN = ''  THEN
predxDiagnosisCode not in (@inpDXNOTIN)
ELSE  predxDiagnosisCode IN (@inpDXIN)
END
```

Even if I could get a snippet of a query using a similar statement i can figure mine out but i cant find anything similar. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: can you provide sample values for `@inpDXNOTIN` and `@inpDXIN` are they strings, memory tables, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't want to use `case` in a `where` clause.  Instead, just use regular boolean logic:

```
Where dnCP_FromServiceDate >= '2016-01-01' and
      dnCP_FromServiceDate <= '2016-01-31' and
      dnCP_RecordStatus <> 'V' and
      ( (@inpDXIN = '' and predxDiagnosisCode <> @inpDXNOTIN) or
        (@inpDXIN <> '' and  predxDiagnosisCode IN (@inpDXIN)
     )
```

Notes:

- Use ISO/ANSI standard date formats.  Much less ambiguous.
- `IN (@var)` is the same as `= @var`.  You cannot pass an `in` list through a variable.  If you need that functionality, then ask *another* question.
- Most dialects of SQL do not allow boolean expressions to be returned from a `case`.  The above gets around this "limitation".

Comment: I think this might overlook the logic hole here - your solution does the same thing as the OP's code: it only checks inpDXIN being empty and never checks inpDXNOTIN.  What if they're both empty?  What if neither is empty?

Comment: @Scott . . . The error in the syntax is the boolean expression for the `else` clause.  The query has several problems, which I tried to address.

Comment: so the above code looked like it might help but it is bringing me back the variable that i dont want in the results

Comment: @KatherinePacheco . . . The above code only *filters* the results.  It does not affect what columns are returned.